# Should session_start always be called?

Tags: php, session, session-state

I noticed that there's a tmp/ folder on my webserver that contains thousands and thousands of session-id files. So I thought it's probably better to only call session_start() when I am actually writing something into the session (login) and then only call it, if there's a logged in user active.

I couldn't find too much on the topic (and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is possible even), just a couple of people saying that session_start() should **always** be called. Does that make sense? And isn't it a performance issue if all these session-ids are stored?

Comment: `session_start()` has to be called if you are using any session data and it makes sense to call it at the start of the script (depending on architecture of you application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I thought it's probably better to only call session_start() when I am actually writing something into the session (login) and then only call it, if there's a logged in user active.

If you set up a login system in any vaguely traditional way that involves sessions, there is no way to tell if you have a logged in user without calling `session_start`.

> just a couple of people saying that session_start() should always be called. Does that make sense?

Yes. If you are going to interact with a session — be it to write to the session, or read from it — then call `session_start()`.

Most websites that deal with login sessions will put a "You are logged in as Bob: click here to logout" or "You are not logged in: click here to log in" message on every page, so most websites will need to call `sessions_start()` on every page.

> And isn't it a performance issue if all these session-ids are stored?

No.

It has a performance *impact*, but that impact is probably negligible. If it becomes a problem, worry about it then.

[Don't try to solve performance problems you don't have.](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)